# How to get all the dates from a loop

Tags: php, datetime, foreach, while-loop

I am preparing a festival site. I have a table with a datetime field for the festival dates. 
Festival will be in between "6 / March / 2013" and " 7 / April / 2013". 
So I created the loop as in these answer here :

```
Schema::create('dates',function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        $starting_date = new DateTime('2013-03-06');
        $ending_date = new DateTime('2013-04-06');

        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
        $period = new  DatePeriod($starting_date , $interval, $ending_date);

        foreach($period as $dt)
        {

        DB::table('dates')->insert(array(
        'date' => $dt
        ));

        }
```

The database is filled until 4th of april , the loop does not add  more than 30 days. 
Can you help me to find a fix for missing days ?

ps: I used alternative while loop resulting same:

```
    $starting_date = new DateTime('2013-03-06');        
            $ending_date = new DateTime('2013-04-07');

            while($starting_date <= $ending_date){
                DB::table('dates')->insert(array(
                    'date' => $starting_date
                ));

            }
    $starting_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

Comment: have you tried while(strtotime($starting_date) <= strtotime($ending_date))   ?

Comment: I applied your suggestion. strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string ... I get this error.

Comment: Don't use the `DateTime` object when passing the times to `strtotime`. For example: `$starting_date = '2013-03-06'`

Comment: use like $starting_date = '2013-03-06', same for end date and then compare directly like :-
while($starting_date <= $ending_date){

Comment: how can I add one day in that format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
just add 23:59:59 to the end of the $ending_date
$starting_date = new DateTime('2013-03-06 00:00');
$ending_date = new DateTime('2013-04-06 23:59:59');


$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new  DatePeriod($starting_date , $interval, $ending_date);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."<br/>";
}
print_r($period);exit;
```

Which outputs

2013-03-06
2013-03-07
2013-03-08
2013-03-09
2013-03-10
2013-03-11
2013-03-12
2013-03-13
2013-03-14
2013-03-15
2013-03-16
2013-03-17
2013-03-18
2013-03-19
2013-03-20
2013-03-21
2013-03-22
2013-03-23
2013-03-24
2013-03-25
2013-03-26
2013-03-27
2013-03-28
2013-03-29
2013-03-30
2013-03-31
2013-04-01
2013-04-02
2013-04-03
2013-04-04
2013-04-05
2013-04-06

Answer (score 2):

A very quick and dirty solution I came up with is:

```
$starting_date = strtotime('2013-03-06');
$ending_date = strtotime('2013-04-06');

while($starting_date <= $ending_date)
{
    echo date('d/m/y', $starting_date) . '<br />';
    $starting_date = strtotime('1 day', $starting_date);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
06/03/13
07/03/13
08/03/13
09/03/13
10/03/13
11/03/13
12/03/13
13/03/13
14/03/13
15/03/13
16/03/13
17/03/13
18/03/13
19/03/13
20/03/13
21/03/13
22/03/13
23/03/13
24/03/13
25/03/13
26/03/13
27/03/13
28/03/13
29/03/13
30/03/13
31/03/13
01/04/13
02/04/13
03/04/13
04/04/13
05/04/13
06/04/13
```

You can simply replace the echo with your query.

Comment: still gives me 30 days with that method.until 4th of april

Comment: Based on my example, it is returning more than 30, however if it is only "inserting" 30, this could be a limitation of your database. 1) ensure errors are being shown, i.e. `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and then add `echo date('d/m/y', $starting_date) . '<br />';` beneath your database insert. I suspect there is a database error that you are not seeing.